# Formatter function call twice in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to display data in jqGrid with a special field called as TransactionNumber. This field is custom control means custom html(two html tags img & span).

---

### Theme / Goal to achieve

1. When the transcation column has value it should show golden arrow(img) and if it does not contains value it should not show golden arrow (img).
2. After editing row this golden arrow(img) should also hide, as there is some custom control which already has this.

---

My Custom Controls will look like this.

```
<img src="../img/link.jpg"/><span>Manual/2839</span>
```

Please see the below screen shot.
[image]

**After certain investigation I found some facts.**
1. Formatter function call twice for each row.
2. In first attempt cellvalue variable is undefined and rowobject does not contains actual row data.
3. In second attempt cellvalue variable contains actual value and rowobject contains actual data.
4. After editing the row, value for the column is :

```
<img onclick="javascript:alert();" src="img/LinkButton_Transperent.png">Manual/1011197
```

which I am not expecting, I am expecting only value and not the image.
Is this a correct behaviour? I assume that it should call only once.

Please see my below snippet.

```js
 $("#uxStages").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'xmlstring',
            datastr: xmlstring,
            mtype: 'GET',
            pager: '#uxStagesMap',
            ajaxGridOptions: {
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            },
            xmlReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: "BO>SalesOpportunitiesLines",
                row: 'row'
            },
            colNames: ['..', 'LineNum', 'Start Date', 'Close Date', 'Sales Employee', 'Stage', 'Percentage', 'Potential Amount', 'Document Type', 'DocEntry', 'Doc. No.', 'Owner'],
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 40, align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'actions',


                    formatoptions: {
                        keys: true, // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.
                        onEdit: function (rowid) {
                            var grid = $("#uxStages");
                            var selectedRowId = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                            lastSelection = selectedRowId;
                            grid.jqGrid('editRow', selectedRowId, true, null, null, null, null, OnSuccessEdit_Stages);
                            $('#' + selectedRowId + "_StageKey").css('width', '100%');
                            $('#' + selectedRowId + "_SalesPerson").css('width', '100%');
                            $('#' + selectedRowId + "_DataOwnershipfield").css('width', '100%');
                            $('#' + selectedRowId + "_DocumentType").css('width', '100%');
                            //$('#' + selectedRowId + "_DocumentNumber").css('width', '100%').css('height', '13.37px').css('padding','2px').css('border','1px');
                            //    $(this).MessageBox('error', 'Cannot Add Stage for Current DocStatus');
                        },
                        onSuccess: function (jqXHR) {
                            return true;
                        },
                        onError: function (rowid, jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            alert("in onError used only for remote editing:" +
                                        "\nresponseText=" + jqXHR.responseText +
                                        "\nstatus=" + jqXHR.status +
                                        "\nstatusText" + jqXHR.statusText +
                                        "\n\nWe don't need return anything");
                        },
                        afterSave: function (rowid) {
                            //debugger;
                            OnSuccessEdit_Stages(rowid, null, null);
                        },
                        afterRestore: function (rowid) {
                            // alert("in afterRestore (Cancel): rowid="+rowid+"\nWe don't need return anything");
                        },
                        delOptions: function (rowid) {
                            //debugger;
                        }

                    }

                },
                {
                    name: 'LineNum', key: true, index: 'LineNum', hidden: true, sortable: false, width: 60
                },
                {
                    name: 'StartDate', key: false, index: 'StartDate', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 75,
                    editable: true,
                    formatter: 'date',
                    formatoptions: {
                        srcformat: 'Ymd',
                        newformat: 'd-m-Y'
                    },
                    formatter: function (cellValue, opts, rawdata, action) {
                        //    debugger;
                        if (action === "edit") {
                            // input data have format "dd-mm-yy" format - "20-03-2015"
                            var input = cellValue.split("-");
                            if (input.length === 3) {
                                return input[0] + "-" + input[1] + "-" + input[2];
                            }
                        } else if (cellValue.length === 8) {
                            // input data have format "yymmdd" format - "20150320"
                            var year = cellValue.substr(0, 4),
       month = cellValue.substr(4, 2),
       day = cellValue.substr(6, 2);
                            return day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                        }
                        return cellValue;
                        // for empty input for example
                    },
                    editoptions: {
                        dataInit: function (elem) {
                            $(elem).datepicker({
                                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'ClosingDate',
                    key: false,
                    index: 'ClosingDate',
                    sortable: false,
                    align: "left",
                    width: 75,
                    editable: true,
                    formatter: 'date',
                    formatoptions: {
                        srcformat: 'Ymd',
                        newformat: 'd-m-Y'
                    },
                    formatter: function (cellValue, opts, rawdata, action) {
                        if (action === "edit") {
                            // input data have format "dd-mm-yy" format - "20-03-2015"
                            var input = cellValue.split("-");
                            if (input.length === 3) {
                                return input[0] + "-" + input[1] + "-" + input[2];
                            }
                        } else if (cellValue.length === 8) {
                            // input data have format "yymmdd" format - "20150320"
                            var year = cellValue.substr(0, 4),
       month = cellValue.substr(4, 2),
       day = cellValue.substr(6, 2);
                            return day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
                        }
                        return cellValue;
                        // for empty input for example
                    },
                    editoptions: {
                        dataInit: function (elem) {
                            $(elem).datepicker({
                                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'SalesPerson',
                    key: false,
                    index: 'SalesPerson',
                    sortable: false,
                    width: 80,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "select",
                    formatter: 'select'
                },
            {
                name: 'StageKey',
                key: false,
                index: 'StageKey',
                hidden: false,
                sortable: false,
                width: 80,
                editable: true,
                edittype: "select",
                formatter: 'select'

            },
            {
                name: 'PercentageRate',
                key: false,
                index: 'PercentageRate',
                sortable: false,
                editable: true,
                width: 60
            }, {
                name: 'MaxLocalTotal',
                key: false,
                index: 'MaxLocalTotal',
                sortable: false,
                width: 100,
                editable: true,
                edittype: "text",
                formatter: 'currency',
                formatoptions: {
                    thousandsSeparator: ','
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'DocumentType', key: false, index: 'DocumentType', sortable: false, width: 60, editable: true,
                edittype: 'select', formatter: 'select',
                editoptions: {
                    value: "bodt_MinusOne:;bodt_Quotation:Sales Quotation;bodt_Order:Sales Order;bodt_DeliveryNote:Deliveries;bodt_Invoice:Sales Invoice;bodt_PurchaseQutation: Purchase Quotation;bodt_PurchaseOrder:Purchase Order;bodt_PurchaseDeliveryNote:Goods Receipt PO;bodt_PurchaseInvoice:Purchase Invoice;"
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'DocumentNumber', key: false, index: 'DocumentNumber', sortable: false, width: 40,
                hidden: false
            },
            {
                name: 'TransactionNumber',
                key: false,
                index: 'TransactionNumber',
                sortable: false,
                editable: true,
                width: 70,
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    debugger;
                    if (rowObject.hasOwnProperty('LineNum')) {
                        if (cellvalue == null || cellvalue == '')
                            return '';//'<span>'+cellvalue+'</span>';
                        else
                            return '<img src="img/LinkButton_Transperent.png" onclick="javascript:alert();" /><span>' + cellvalue + '</span> ';
                    }
                    else
                        return '<span>' + cellvalue + '</span> ';
                },
                editoptions: {
                     
                    dataInit: function (elem) {
                        $(elem).css('width', '98%')
                        .css('text-align', 'center')
                        .css('padding-left', '1px')
                        .css('padding-right', '1px')
                        .css('padding-top', '2px')
                        .css('padding-bottom', '2px');

                        $(elem).ChooseFromListAndLink({
                            init: function () { },
                            defaultValue: $(elem).val(),
                            LinkImage: 'img/LinkButton_Transperent.png',
                            ChooseFromListImage: 'img/choosefromlist.png',
                            OnLinkClick: function (evt) {
                                alert('Underconstruction');
                            },
                            OnListClick: function (evt) {
                                var selectedRowId = $("#uxStages").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                OpenRelatedDocument(selectedRowId);
                            },
                            OpenListOnTab: true
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, {
                name: 'DataOwnershipfield', key: false, index: 'DataOwnershipfield', hidden: false, sortable: false, width: 75,
                editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select'
            }
            ],
            rowNum: 100,
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            height: 130,
            loadonce: true,
            width: 1260,
            ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
                //var grid = $("#uxStages");
                //var selectedRowId = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                //lastSelection = selectedRowId;
                //grid.jqGrid('editRow', selectedRowId, true, null, null, null, null, OnSuccessEdit_Stages);
                //$('#' + selectedRowId + "_StageKey").css('width', '100%');
                //$('#' + selectedRowId + "_SalesPerson").css('width', '100%');
                //$('#' + selectedRowId + "_DataOwnershipfield").css('width', '100%');
                //$('#' + selectedRowId + "_DocumentType").css('width', '100%');
            },
            loadComplete: function () {

                var stagevalues = GetStagesValues();
                var salesvalues = GetSalesValues();
                // name of sales person 
                var owners = GetDataOwnershipValues();
                //name of employees
                $("#uxStages").setColProp('SalesPerson', {
                    edittype: "select",
                    editoptions: {
                        value: salesvalues
                    }
                });
                //Here i m fetching values in namedvalue pairs
                $("#uxStages").setColProp('StageKey', {
                    edittype: "select",
                    editoptions: {
                        value: stagevalues,
                        dataEvents: [

                                     {
                                         type: 'change',
                                         fn: function (event) {
                                             var selectedRowID = $("#uxStages").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                             var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                                             $('#uxOOST').each(function () {
                                                 $('option', this).each(function () {
                                                     var id = $(this).val();
                                                     if (id == selectedValue) {
                                                         var val = $(this).attr('TagName');
                                                         $('#uxStages').jqGrid('setCell', selectedRowID, 'PercentageRate', val);
                                                     }
                                                 });
                                             });
                                         }

                                     }

                        ]
                    }
                });
                //Here i m fetching values in namedvalue pairs
                $("#uxStages").setColProp('DataOwnershipfield', {
                    edittype: "select",
                    editoptions: {
                        value: owners
                    }
                });
                //Here i m fetching values in namedvalue pairs
                // debugger;
                var ids = $("#uxStages").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                    var id = ids[i];
                    var SalesPerson = $('#uxStages').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'SalesPerson');
                    //getting text part of select and expected to get value
                    var StageKey = $('#uxStages').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'StageKey');
                    //getting text part of select and expected to get value
                    var DataOwnershipfield = $('#uxStages').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'DataOwnershipfield');
                    //getting text part of select and expected to get value
                    $("#uxStages").editRow(id, true);

                    $("#" + id + "_SalesPerson").each(function () {
                        $('option', this).each(function () {
                            var code = $(this).val();
                            if (code == SalesPerson) $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                        });
                    });
                    $("#" + id + "_StageKey").each(function () {
                        $('option', this).each(function () {
                            var code = $(this).val();
                            if (code == StageKey) $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                        });
                    });
                    $("#" + id + "_DataOwnershipfield").each(function () {
                        $('option', this).each(function () {
                            var code = $(this).val();
                            if (code == DataOwnershipfield) $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                        });
                    });
                    if (i < ids.length - 1) {

                        $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(id)).addClass('not-editable-row');
                        $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(id)).addClass('ui-state-error');
                    }
                    //desable All rows of grid for Won & Lost DocStatus
                    if ($('#Radio2').prop('checked') || ($('#Radio3').prop('checked'))) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                            $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(i), "#uxStages").addClass('not-editable-row');
                            $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(i), "#uxStages").addClass('ui-state-error');
                        }
                    }
                    $("#uxStages").saveRow(id);
                }
            },
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                if (id && id !== lastSelection) {
                    var grid = $("#uxStages");
                    $('#uxStages').saveRow(lastSelection);
                }
            }
        }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#uxStagesMap', {
            add: false,
            del: false,
            edit: false,
            remove: false,
            refresh: false,
            searchOnEnter: false,
            search: false
        }, {}, {}, {}, {
            multipleSearch: false
        });
```

Does anyone know why it behave like this? 
or do I lack in knowledge of jqGrid.

Comment: It's important to know **which version of jqGrid you use?** Different versions of jqGrid have a little different parameters for custom formatters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `datatype: 'xmlstring'` which is origin of many problems which you have. For example you use `rowObject.hasOwnProperty('LineNum')` inside of the custom formatter, but the 3-d parameter of the custom formatter (`rowObject`) have **different type** on the initial processing of input data. You will have Element with XML node instead of object with `LineNum` property. On the later loading the 3-d parameter of the custom formatter will be object.

Such behavior makes implementation of custom formatter more complex. One can of cause write two different parts inside of custom formatters. Alternatively jqGrid could be changed to simplify processing of the data. The main problem is the **compatibility with the previously versions**. If somebody wrote already formatter which process `rawdata` (`rowObject`) as XML node then such code will be broken after updating the new version of jqGrid would could use simplified form of `rawdata` (`rowObject`). Because of the compatibility problem I made another change in the interface of custom formatter in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). The version 4.9 and later versions of free jqGrid *extends the second (`options`) parameter of custom formatter* with required information.

The common interface of custom formatter is

```
formatter: function (cellValue, options, rawdata, action) {
     ...
}
```

The format of `rawdata` stay unchanged, but `options.rowData` will contains **always** simple object with parsed input data. So you can safe use `options.rowData.LineNum`. Even if `rawdata` is XML node and `rawdata.LineNum` will be undefined, the `options.rowData.LineNum` will provide you the required information.

By the way the formatter will be called at the end of editing too. If the format of the data after editing is another as the format of initial input data then you can test `action` for values `"add"` or `"edit"` to distinguish two cases and to prevent including of `image` if it is not needed after editing.

Comment: Ok. Got it, But when I load data in jqGrid format function calls for each row. I don't understand that why it calls twice, ideally it should call only once. is it required to call twice?

Comment: @Manish: It should be called *once*. I recommend you to debug the code. I suppose the the second call exist because you use very complex `loadComplete`. The call of `getCell` follows to unformatting of data from the column. The call of `editRow` will also call unformatter and `saveRow` calls formatters. All the code makes filling of the grid much more slowly and it could be origin of the second call of formatters too.

Comment: Oh, I see, Thats great Oleg,  Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example (take a look in the last column called myCustomData):

```
grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: mydata,
        colModel:[
            { label: 'Code', name: 'TransactionCode', width: 10, align:'center', editable:true, formatter : 'integer', sorttype: "float", formatoptions: {thousandsSeparator: ".", defaultValue: '0'}},
            { label: 'Reader Name', name: 'Description', width: 20, editable:true },
            { label: 'Serial Number', name: 'SerialNumber', width: 15, align:'center', editable:true },
            { label: 'Start Transaction', name: 'DateTimeStartTransaction', width: 20,  align:'center', editable:true, formatter : 'date', formatoptions: {srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat:'d/m/Y H:i:s'}  },
            { label: 'End Transaction', name: 'DateTimeEndTransaction', width: 20,  align:'center', editable:true, formatter : 'date', formatoptions: {srcformat: 'ISO8601Long', newformat:'d/m/Y H:i:s'}  },
            { label: 'Additional Information', name: 'Status', width: 20, align:'center', editable:true },
            {
                label: ' ',
                name:'myCustomData',
                width: 7,
                align:'center',
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject ) {
                    buttons = '<a href="editinvalid?transactionCode=' + rowObject.TransactionCode + '&dateTimeStartTransaction=' + rowObject.DateTimeStartTransaction + '"><img src="<?=Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/images/edit.png'?>"> </a>';
                    return buttons;
                }
            },
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        height: "100%",
        width: 1070,
        rowNum: 15,
        pager: '#pager_contacts',
    });
```